# What is the best way to upgrade python in a virtual environment using virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, upgrade, virtualenvwrapper

I created an environment using virtualenvwrapper while my machine was running Python 3.8.3. Naturally, this made the environment with Python 3.8.3 as well.

Later, I updated Python on my main machine using home brew to 3.10.

Now I have 3.10-specific code in the virtual env project, running 3.8.3.

The first entry in that project's $PATH is set to the virtual env itself, which uses the old Python. The 2nd entry is Python 3.10. I believe this is standard. The virtual env itself is added to the front of $PATH by virtualenverapper upon activation.

Short of manually manipulating the .zprofile or a virtalenvwrapper's postactivate script, I am wondering if there is a more sweeping and automatic way of updating a virtual environment using virtualenvwarpper?

I am no expert on this stuff, so my concern is that manually manipulating files, or applying one-time fixes will just be asking for trouble down the line.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I wanted to add that I am also learning git and have a repo set up in this project. I would like to ideally preserve that information through the "upgrade," which it sounds like involves creating a new env. The virtualenvs are stored on the ~user directory in .virtualenvs. The git repo is in the project directory.

Comment: Export your installed package list (e.g., with `pip list` or `pip freeze`) when inside the old v-env, then exit the v-env and recreate a new v-env with your Python 3.10.

Comment: what are the ramifications of recreating the env with regard to git? Do I have to initialize a new git repository too?

Comment: I assume the Git folder is related to your project? Your project should be living outside where your v-envs are stored. You should be able to continue working on your project normally. Any installations such as `pip install -e .` will then occur in the new v-env (so perhaps remove your project from the list from `pip list/freeze`, if it's in there). But Git is otherwise completely independent from a v-env, Python or Pip.

Comment: Since you don't mention Git in your question, you should perhaps clarify its usage in your question. Is it used to install from e.g. GitHub or GitLab directly? Or is it used to manage a project that you are developing using this v-env? And what are you using the v-env itself for: for developing a project, or running a (not yours) project?

Comment: Edit added for clarification, thank you.

Comment: "have a repo set up in this project": that is an incorrect formulation. The "project", whatever that is, is stored/versioned by the repository. If you mean the v-env: that is an environment (of Python packages) that helps the project. Both Git/a repository and a v-env (or any environment, e.g. a Conda one) are not inherent to the project, but assist the project. I would neither have to use Git nor virtualenv to use your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this. As you said, even if you pulled it off you're sure to have hidden issues that'll be a major headache down the line. Fortunately, it's very easy to recreate the virtual env with exactly the same installed packages you had before but with a new Python version.

What you want is to compile a list of installed packages in your old virtualenv, make your new venv with the desired Python version, then reinstall all the packages. We can do this simply like this :

```
workon oldenv
pip freeze > env_requirements.txt
deactivate
mkvirtualenv newenv -p `which python3.10`
pip install -r env_requirements.txt
```

If you're happy with the result, you can then delete the old venv :

```
rmvirtualenv oldenv
```

---

As to your concern with git, this should have absolutely no impact whatsoever on your git repo.

Comment: Thanks, I was just writing out a comment and saw yours re: git. That's great to know. Thinking about it, the way I interact with virtualenvwrapper abstracts the whole env workflow to make it seem more connected to the project directory than it really is. There's basically no connection really, huh.

Comment: Yes, they're quite separate. In fact you can work on multiple repositories within the same venv if you expect them to eventually be deployed in the same environment. Very frequently you have one venv per repo, but there's nothing that mechanically ties the 2. It's just a common pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked. Interesting, also learned the ` ` is not the same as " " . Does this type of syntax have a name? I'd like to learn more what this is.

Comment: It's called `command substitution` and is a very common shell trick. It takes the output of one command and expands it to be part of the current command. In this case it avoids having to find the path to python3.10 and copying and pasting it to your command. The `which` command does this for you and `command substitution` passes it as an argument to the `p` flag when using `mkvirtualenv`.